Unable to Generate Spark Report
I am encountering an issue where I am unable to generate a Spark report using the com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter: plugin. Despite following the setup instructions, the report is not being created.
Steps to Reproduce:

Add the following dependency to pom.xml:

 <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>



Configure the extent.properties file with the following settings:
extent.reporter.spark.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/SparkReport/Spark.html
Run the test using the configured test runner class.

@Suite
@SelectClasspathResource("feature_files")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "StepDefs")
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}

Expected Behavior:
A Spark report should be generated in the specified output directory.
Actual Behavior:
No report is generated, and there are no error messages in the logs.
Environment:

Cucumber version: 7.16.1
Java version: 21
Maven version:3.2.5

I tried to change version of extentreports-cucumber7-adapter but didn't work with me `

You are using
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
)

Which is used to configure Cucumber for JUnit 4. You however are using JUnit 5.
So you should:

Remove cucumber-junit from your dependencies. This will prevent any possibility of future confusion.
Replace @CucumberOptions with @ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:")

For other configuration options please read the documentation.
